# Is it expensive to hold on to PreparedStatements? (Java & JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to figure out if it's efficient for me to cache all of my statements when I create my database connection or if I should only create those that are most used and create the others if/when they're needed..

It seems foolish to create *all* of the statements in *all* of the client threads.  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit decent database will already cache them. Just fire `Connection#prepareStatement()` at the moment you actually need to execute the query. You actually also have no other choice since connection, statement and resultset ought to be acquired and closed in the *shortest possible* scope, i.e. in a `try-finally` block in the very same method as you execute the query.

Opening and closing the connection on every query in turn may indeed be expensive. A common solution to that is using a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool), for example [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/).

Answer (score 4):

I think you're worrying too much, prepared statements already benefit from several level of caching:

- At the database level: a decent database will reuse the access plan for a given prepared statement.
- At the connection pool level: a decent connection pool will cache `PreparedStatement` objects for each database connection in the pool (and return a cached `PreparedStatement` on subsequent calls to `preparedStatement` on a connection).

So actually, I would even say that you might be looking in the wrong direction. The best practice if you want to design a scalable solution is to use a connection pool and to not held a connection longer than needed and to release it (to release database resources) when you're done with it.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like the kind of premature optimization that I wouldn't worry about until I have some information telling me that it mattered.  If your database access is inefficient, I'd suspect your schema or access of values before I'd think of caching prepared statements.